# is it possible that android proguard cause missfunction of app?

Tags: android, proguard, digital-compass

i am writing an app that one part of it is a compass, it show right direction before, i adding 2 or 3 activity to app that is unrelated to compass activity, also used android proguard(with default setting not the optimized one), as result the compass going to act like crazy, it show a different direction on any devices( actually it's too funny).
**so can you suggest something to help me?**
[image]

Comment: You should call it a "Tates Compass" because then your advertising tag line could be "He who has a Tates is lost"! (On a slightly more serious note: does your app work properly on all those devices with the new activities if you disable ProGuard?)

Comment: @Keyser: actually it works fin on my device(htc chacha, android 2.3), this devices you see in image (i think) they are all android 4.x).  is it related?

Comment: @TedHopp: i'm sure that before (when it worked fine) i used proguard too.

Comment: Then it's most likely that the problem is caused by the additional activities, not by ProGuard. (I know that you say they are unrelated to the compass function, but still, if that's what changed....) If you remove the new activities, does correct compass functionality return?

Comment: i compile it again (without any change to code) and it work fine. what happened? i don't know.